# Changing button background color removes white space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am changing some button background colors before the activity is shown and  when the buttons are displayed, they are missing the white space around them.

[image]

How do I get the buttons to be red, where the grey is, and keep the white spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `red_button.xml` in `drawable` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#80FFFFFF" />

  <corners android:radius="25dp" />

  <gradient android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#ff0000"
            android:endColor="#ff0000"
            android:startColor="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

To get same shape as the default `Button`

You can play around with `radius` and `stroke width` and `stroke color` to get your `Button` as you want.

EDIT: You can add the color to original default `Button` like this:

```
Drawable d = yourButton.getBackground();  
PorterDuffColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);  // or whatever color you like
d.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Can I do this via code rather them putting it in the XML?

Comment: Why would you like to do it in code? Create the XML and just add in code your background with button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);

Comment: I'd like to do it via code, as I am setting the background color via code. If I made a generic button layout, and set it with setBackgroundResource(), can I change the background color inside it with code? so I don't need one layout for each color I require?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, it's a lot! That why also wrote that he can play around with those values.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have missed setting margin for layout. Actually there is a white space around your button so all the buttons are touched, so when you set background that white space also turns red. This should be okay I guess.!

Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gallery" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Media" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In strings.xml

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

In Java

```
   one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);
        one.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        two.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        three.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

Output

[image: This is your desired output?]